# Doing addition and comparing columns in WHERE statement

Tags: mysql, database

So I am trying to run a query which does some math in the `WHERE` statement.  It seems that what I wrote is correct, yet it does not seem to work.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE col_a + col_b != col_d
```

Basically I want to see all records where `col_a` added to `col_b` does not add up to `col_d`.

Comment: What are the column datatypes? Example data where it doesn't work?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73e67/2 - your query works if the data types are `INT`.

Comment: So please supply an example of a row that is brought back that you think shouldn't be (or not brought back that you think should be)

Answer (score 2):

I can think of three reasons why this might not seem to work.

The first is the most likely:  that one or more of the values are NULL.  To fix this, use COALESCE:

```
where coalesce(col_a, 0) + coalesce(col_b, 0) <> coalesce(col_d, 0)
```

Another reason would be that the results look to you like they are the same, but in the floating point presentation, they are really different.  So, 0.999999999 + 5.0 might look like "6.0" but it is not equal to "6.0", because the difference is at a distant decimal point.

The third reason is arithmetic overflow or a typing problem (mixing tiny integers with floats or the like).

Comment: The fourth reason might be operator precedence (not sure with MySQL). It could be getting interpreted as 'col_a + (col_b != col_d)`, and placing parentheses would fix: `WHERE (col_a + col_b) != col_d`. As I said, I'm not sure of the precedence order in MySQL though, so it may not apply. (I'd appreciate it if you'd let me know if it does or not for future reference, though.)

Comment: @KenWhite - [No, checked that already](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html) `+` has higher precedence than `!=`

Comment: @MartinSmith: Thanks for that info. I'll tuck that away for next time. (I don't use MySQL, so I couldn't check myself.)